# ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional......verify_integrity

Tags: pandas, numpy, shapes

Bonjour,

> I don't understand why this issue occurs.

```
print("p.shape= ", p.shape)
print("dfmj_dates['deces'].shape = ",dfmj_dates['deces'].shape)
cross_dfmj = pd.crosstab(p, dfmj_dates['deces'])
```

> That produces:

```
p.shape=  (683, 1)
dfmj_dates['deces'].shape =  (683,)


----> 3 cross_dfmj = pd.crosstab(p, dfmj_dates['deces'])
--> 654     df = DataFrame(data, index=common_idx)
--> 614             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
--> 589             val = sanitize_array(
--> 576     subarr = _sanitize_ndim(subarr, data, dtype, index, allow_2d=allow_2d)
--> 627             raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")
ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

> From me, I suspect issue comes from the difference between (683, 1)
> and (683,).  I tried something like p.flatten(order = 'C') to get
> (683,)  but pd.DataFrame(dfmj_dates['deces']) too. That failed.
> Do you have any idea? Regards, Atapalou

---

```
print(p.head(30))
print(df.head(30))
```

> that produces

```
    week
0      8
1      8
2      8
3      9
4      9
5      9
6      9
7      9
8      9
9      9
10    10
11    10
12    10
13    10
14    10
15    10
16    10
17    11
18    11
19    11
20    11
21    11
22    11
23    11
24    12
25    12
26    12
27    12
28    12
29    12
    deces
0       0
1       1
2       0
3       0
4       0
5       1
6       0
7       0
8       0
9       0
10      1
11      1
12      0
13      3
14      4
15      5
16      3
17     11
18      3
19     15
20     13
21     18
22     12
23     36
24     21
25     27
26     69
27    128
28     78
29    112
```

Comment: Please prepare a small example of `p` and `dfmj_dates['deces']` in the body of the question. These are used in your question but not defined. Put them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `squeeze` p:

```
cross_dfmj = pd.crosstab(p.squeeze(), dfmj_dates['deces'])
```

Example:

```
p = np.random.random((5, 1))
p.shape
# (5, 1)

p.squeeze().shape
# (5,)
```

Comment: In fact, my solution should not work as you use something similar `p.flatten`. Can you provide a sample of `p` and `dfmj_dates['deces']`, please

Comment: I don't get any more issue with squeeze(). I don't know why.